# Balls into Bins: probability that b bins have at least m balls

Tags: probability, stirling-numbers, balls-in-bins

Consider the standard balls into bins problem, with $n$ balls uniformly randomly thrown into $k$ bins.

What is the probability that exactly $b$ bins have at least $m$ balls?

This is a generalization of the standard problem where we want to know the probability that exactly $b$ bins have at least $1$ ball (non-empty) - I know that you can use stirling numbers of the second kind to derive a closed form solution for this. Is it possible to generalize this to the event of having at least $m$ balls?

Comment: Can you distinguish in between the bins?

Comment: The bins may be ordered, but the event in question speaks only about the number of bins, not which particular ones they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint/Approach:** A way to extend the definition of Stirling numbers are the "[Associated Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#cite_ref-14)", they are denoted by ${ n\brace k}_{\geq m},$ where this means the number of partitions of $[n]$ into $k$ blocks, each one having at least $m$ elements. So, most likely if you know that the formula involves taking Stirling numbers, you can change that for these associated. You can easily check that they satisfy the following recursion
$${n+1\brace k}_{\geq m} = \sum _{j = m-1}^n\binom{n}{j}{n-j\brace k-1}_{\geq m},$$ by checking the elements that are in the same block as the element $n+1.$

Comment: Do you know if associated stirling numbers of the second kind have a closed form representation or if they can be represented in terms of normal stirling numbers?

Comment: Not really, you can express associated with $m$ in terms of associated with $m+1$ so it goes up the dependency. I dont think there is a nice closed formula. By nice i mean not like adding all possible sizes with binomials.